# ¿Qué quiere decir "hablar por boca de ganso"? ¿Cuál es su origen?

Tags: modismos, españa, locuciones

Leía hace poco en [un artículo](http://www.eldiario.es/zonacritica/Puigdemont-da-marcha_6_694390590.html):

> Desde que el jefe del Estado **habló por boca de ganso** el lunes pasado, Puigdemont debe de saber que esta vez va en serio, que todo eso, o algo parecido, puede ocurrir o, mejor, ocurrirá si hace la DUI.

Parece que se refiere a que una persona (en este caso *el jefe del Estado*, es decir el rey de España) dijo algo que otro ya había dicho en el pasado. Parece, pues, que está diciendo que dos personas de poder ya han dicho lo mismo.

En efecto, explica el DLE en [*boca*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5i6aRwS):

> **hablar alguien por boca de ganso**
>   1. locución verbal coloquial Decir lo que otro le ha sugerido.

Pero no entra en más explicaciones. ¿Alguien lo usa? ¿Conocéis su origen? ¿Se usa en otros lugares que no sea España?

Comment: La expresión no significa que el rey dijera algo que otro ya había dicho antes, sino que decía lo que otro le había pedido. En este caso, el gobierno. Los discursos del rey, salvo el de Nochebuena, los escribe el gobierno. Esto mismo lo estamos viendo ahora en el Reino Unido, donde, durante la sesión de apertura del parlamento, la reina leyó un discurso que había escrito el gobierno.

Comment: Respecto a la última pregunta, en Colombia nunca lo he escuchado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues antigua es, ya que aparece en el *Diccionario de Autoridades*:

> Hablar por *boca* de ganso. Es hablar lo que otro le sugiére para que lo diga, apuntandoselo, ò enseñandoselo à este fin en secréto, ò antes, para que esté prevenido quando llegue el caso de hablar.

En el CORDE se encuentran algunos casos, algunos muy explicativos como este:

> *Ya sabemos que mamá no habla más que por boca de ganso; lo que tú le mandas decir.*
>
> Elena Soriano, "Caza menor", 1951 (España).

Los casos más antiguos son los de Francisco de Quevedo, por ejemplo:

> *Vino en paga, y vino bien;
>
>   que tiene muchas quejosas,
>
>   y al Tonante sin dinero
>
>   le llamaran Pocarropa.
>
>   Habló por boca de ganso
>
>   a Leda, y con la tramoya
>
>   de plumas blancas y pico,
>
>   dios avechucho, engañóla.*
>
> Francisco de Quevedo y Villegas, "Poesías", 1597-1645 (España).

Si volvemos, pues, a tu ejemplo, lo que dice el artículo no es que el jefe del Estado haya dicho lo que otro antes, sino lo que otro le ha preparado que diga. Como si dicha persona fuese una simple marioneta a la que otro le mueve la boca y le pone voz.

Yo, particularmente, nunca había oído la expresión antes, ni siquiera la conocía. Por lo que no te puedo decir si es muy usada. Sí te puedo decir que los casos del CORDE son todos de España (22) menos uno que es de Argentina, lo cual no es prueba de que se conozca en Hispanoamérica, al menos de forma generalizada. La estadística es la misma para el CREA (6 casos en España y 1 en Argentina).

Acerca de su origen, no estoy muy seguro pero he comprobado que en siglo XVI se usaba la denominación *ganso* para los malos poetas, así como *cisne* se usaba para los buenos. Así, Covarrubias nos dice:

> Por ser el claromoso y de voz aspera y desagradable a los oydos, es simbolo del mal Poeta, como el cisne del bueno [...].

De hecho, encontramos este ejemplo en el CORDE:

> *[...] pues juzgan con tan rústicos oídos
>
>   que lo escuchan por cisne, siendo ganso,
>
>   i por canto sonoro sus graznidos.*
>
> Bartolomé Leonardo de Argensola, "Rimas", 1592-a1631 (España).

Luego mi teoría es que el dicho alude a que a los malos poetas les debían de componer los versos otros poetas mejores, muy al estilo de lo que hace Cyrano de Bergerac con Christian de Neuvilette cuando éste habla por boca de ganso a Roxane, usando los versos de aquel, para poder conquistarla.

Answer (score 1):

[Este artículo](http://www.revistaelabasto.com.ar/99_zimmerman.htm) argentino dice que la expresión "hablar por boca de ganso" tiene origen en la pluma del ganso que estudiantes usaron en el pasado para escribir.

> El buen alumno era el que repetía dócilmente lo que su ganso afirmaba. Con el tiempo, el sentido de la frase cambió ligeramente. “Hablar por boca de ganso” equivale a repetir algo de cuya constancia se carece. Quien así habla suele hacerlo con pedantería, respaldándose en el conocimiento de algún otro.

Fuente: [Revista El Abasto](http://www.revistaelabasto.com.ar/99_zimmerman.htm)